# How can I find the root folder of a given subversion working copy

Tags: svn, repository

Quite often I'm sitting in the middle of a subversion working copy, and I want to do a quick `svn status` to find out what changes I have made since the last checkin. However `svn status` only works on the current folder and it's children. (Similarly for `svn up` too)

I'd like a quick way to change to the root folder of the subversion working copy so I can run a `svn status` and see *all* files that have changed, maybe a checkin or a update, and then get back to work where I was before.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's my first go at an answer: I wrote a little bash script called `svnbase`:

```
#!/bin/bash -u

# this command outputs the top-most parent of the current folder that is still 
# under svn revision control to standard out

# if the current folder is not under svn revision control, nothing is output
# and a non-zero exit value is given

parent=""
grandparent="."

while [ -d "$grandparent/.svn" ]; do
    parent=$grandparent
    grandparent="$parent/.."
done

if [ ! -z "$parent" ]; then
    echo $parent
else
    exit 1
fi
```

So now I can do this:

```
[~/work/scripts/XXX/code/speech-detection/framework]$ cd $(svnbase)
[~/work/scripts/XXX]$ svn status
?      code/speech-detection/framework/output.old
[~/work/scripts/XXX]$ cd -
/home/XXXX/work/scripts/XXX/code/speech-detection/framework
[~/work/scripts/XXX/code/speech-detection/framework]$
```

Comment: The next logical step would be to integrate that series of commands you're typing into the script itself.

Comment: If you'd prefer an absolute path rather than a relative one, initialise: `grandparent=$(pwd)`, and each loop: `grandparent=$(dirname parent)`

Comment: This will only work for Subversion versions up to 1.6. Versions 1.7 and later only have a single `.svn` folder in the root folder.

Comment: @ccpizza Then you could just loop up _until_ you find a `.svn` folder, I guess...

Answer (score 10):

On Windows:

```
svn info . |findstr /C:"Working Copy Root Path:"
```

On Linux:

```
svn info . |grep -F "Working Copy Root Path:"
```

It can be assigned to a variable using a little string manipulation. Windows version:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('svn info . ^|findstr /C:"Working Copy Root Path:"') DO SET SOME_TEMP_VAR=%%i
SET WORKING_COPY_ROOT=%SOME_TEMP_VAR:~24%
```

Comment: This will not work if the current subdirectory is not currently tracked as part of svn. The error is svn: warning: W155010: The node 'C:\svn\root\path\to\folder\not\in\svn' was not found.

Comment: On non-English systems this may fail because the text will be localized. To prevent this on Linux, add line `export LC_ALL=C` to your script.

Answer (score 8):

On linux with svn, version 1.9.3 (r1718519), I run this:
`svn info --show-item wc-root`

Comment: Did you mean wc-root? `svn help info` lists this as an option and it appears to work correctly.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. I will update the response.

Answer (score 7):

If you use [`git-svn`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) as your Subversion client, then you can interact transparently with a Subversion repository using Git commands locally. Git automatically shows you pending across the whole repository when you use commands like [`git status`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html) anywhere in the tree.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. SVN can be checked out from any depth, and any subdir acts like brand new checkout.

edit: svnbase script in prev comment works, but it is not precise.

Comment: Parent directory may be a checkout of another repository.

Answer (score 2):

actually, if you look in your .svn/entries file, you'll find the base listed in there usually around line 6. In any event, the format of your svn url will give you some significant clues :P
Oh yeah, i took the liberty of looking, and `svn info` will also tell you.

...sigh, that's not what you asked though. I like the solution in the first answer :P

Comment: the svn info thing list the root of your repository though, not the working copy. So this wouldn't help if you didn't checkout the entire repository, whereas `svnbase` above still would.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command at any depth of your working copy:

```
svn info . --show-item wc-root --no-newline
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, which is a hybrid of various solutions put here. It is written in PowerShell, as I needed it for a PowerShell module I am writing.

```
<#
    This command outputs the top-most parent of the current folder.

    If the current folder is not under svn revision control,
    it will recurse up one level, and try again.

    It stops at the root folder on the current drive.
    If the current folder's drive's root folder is not under svn revision control,
    it will throw an exception "No SVN Root Directory found."
#>
function Get-SvnRootDirectory {
    $currentDirectory = Get-Location

    do {
        $output = $(svn info $currentDirectory 2> $null)
        $output = $output | findstr /C:"Working Copy Root Path:"
        if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        # if (Test-Path -PathType Container -Path $currentDirectory)
        # {
        #     throw "No SVN Root Directory found."
        # }
        $currentDirectory = Split-Path -Path $currentDirectory -Parent
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currentDirectory))
        {
            throw "No SVN Root Directory found."
        }
    }
    while ($true)

    $output -match "Working Copy Root Path: (?<Group>.*)$" | Out-Null
    return $Matches.Group
}
```