# find all subversion working copies on machine

Tags: svn, bash, unix, find

How could I use `find` unix utility to find all working copies on the machine? For example, I can use `find / -name .svn -type d` command, but it outputs all redundant results (a lot of subfolders), while I need only parent directory of working copy to be shown.

There is related question, but it does not really help in my case: [How can I find the root folder of a given subversion working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242364/)

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: I would say that this __IS__ programming related, at least to some extent, Also @bzlm, I was kindly asked to read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/change-the-belongs-on-serverfault-tag-when-a-question-is-moved-to-serverfault/4211#4211

I.e. Please do not retag with belongs-on-xxx tag

Comment: @bzim Comments are OK for expressing an opinion - tags are not. Please do not use tags like "belongs-on-superuser", particularly do NOT replace all the original tags with such a tag - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36819/too-many-questions-are-being-closed-as-not-programming-related/36821#36821

Comment: @neil @Kimvais Thanks, hadn't seen that (don't read meta). I was tricked by the hundreds of implicit votes (in the form of existing tags) for the *belongs-on* tags. (Also, a rollback with a message would have sufficed, since your comments, like this one, are not comments on the question, but on something else. Glad we're all fallible. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maybe something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d "$1/.svn" ]; then
        echo $1
else
        for d in $1/*
        do
                if [ -d "$d" ]; then
                        ( $0 $d )
                fi;
        done
fi;
```

name it, for example - find_svn.sh, make it executable, and call like `./find_svn.sh /var/www` (may need some tweaking to normalize directory name(s), strip trailing slash.. but works for me in this form, when called on some dir without trailing slash).

Answer (score 6):

Update 3 - sorted output of find to ensure .svn comes before hidden files.  still might fail for checked-in hidden directories.

---

Perl can remove the nested paths for you:

```
find -s . -ipath *.svn | perl -lne's!/\.svn$!!i;$a&&/^$a/||print$a=$_'
```

In human, this says: for each svn path, ignoring the `/.svn` part, if the current path is a child of the last path *I printed*, don't print it.

example:  for the directory structure:

```
$ find .
.
./1
./1/.svn
./1/1
./1/1/.svn
./2
./2/.svn
./3
```

this yields

```
./1
./2
```

Comment: nope. it does not work as supposed. child directories are still shown

Comment: can you please give me some example input that fails to work correctly?

Comment: @Alex Brown: I got list of folders as the result

    ./REL_1.0/archive/pubupdate
    ./REL_1.0/archive
    ./REL_1.0/meta
    ./REL_1.0/backend
    ./REL_1.0/doc
    ./REL_1.0/src
    ./REL_1.0

while only REL_1.0 folder is the parent svn repository

Comment: Looks like when you run `find` it is returning the results *depth-first*.  Are you sure you aren't accidentally adding a `-d` or `-depth` option to find (which would have this effect)?  If you can't see it on the command-line, check your `alias`es (run `alias`) and see if `find` has been aliased to `find -d`

Comment: No, find is ok: no aliases or -d flags

Comment: okay, I see what's happening - it's not depth first, it only looks like that after you prune `.svn`.  let's put the sort back in - add a -s option to find.  This will mean that `./REL_1.0/archive/.svn` comes before `/REL_1.0/archive/pubupdate` (and hence `/REL_1.0/archive/pubupdate/.svn`)

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me just fine. It finds also all sparse checkouts (or nested working copies).

```
find $PWD -type d -wholename "*/.svn" |
while read path
do
    path=${path%%/.svn}
    wcr=$(svn info ${path} 2>/dev/null | perl -F"/:\s/" -le '{ print $F[1] if $F[0] =~ /^Working Copy Root/;  }')
    [ "$path" = "$wcr" ] && {
        echo -e "\n  WC Root $path"; svn stat -qu $path;
        }
done
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have GNU find/sort

```
find /path -type f -name ".svn*" -printf "%h\n"  | sort -u
```