# Subversion: Get the branch "root" from the repository

Tags: svn

I've had a little search around for this and can't find anything similar but appols if it is a duplicate and I've jsut missed something...

Problem is this:

I am going through a branch A and getting log history and figuring out what was merged into branch A. Lets say file aaa.txt was merged into branch A from branch B. I then look at the merge source in branch B.

If A is `svn+ssh://myserver.com/branches/people/james/projectA/.../aaa.txt`

and if B is `svn+ssh://myserver.com/branches/trunk/src/.../aaa.txt`

I want to record a branch as being from the line `svn+ssh://myserver.com/branches/trunk/src`

If B was `svn+ssh://myserver.com/branches/people/john/projectA/.../aaa.txt`

I want to record a branch as being from the line `svn+ssh://myserver.com/branches/people/john/projectA`

I had a read of [***this link***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242364/how-can-i-find-the-root-folder-of-a-given-subversion-working-copy) but it describes how I might do this when the repo is checked out locally. However, I need to do this on the server.

I've tried to see what would distinguish the branch root `svn+ssh://myserver.com/branches/people/john/projectA` from `svn+ssh://myserver.com/branches/people/john/projectA/.../aaa.txt` from `svn+ssh://myserver.com/branches/people/john`, but to no avail. The svn `info` and `proplist` for the various dirs doesn't provide anything useful to distinguish the difference.

Anyone have ideas?

I should mention I would like to detect this automatically. Currently I am resorting to one of 2 methods: either use rules about the repo layout or find a directory that matches a known pattern to find the root of a development line. Ideally I'd like to to have to rely on specific bits of knowledge that would be repo dependent.... but I'm thinking svn might not support what I want to do?