# Get root directory of SVN repository using Python

Tags: python, svn

I am trying to figure out how to find the root directory of an SVN repository in Python so that I don't always need to hardcode paths to files. Below is what I use for Git and is exactly what I need, only for SVN. I tried using `svn info`, but this refers to the URL and not the root directory where I have the repo checked out.

```
def get_git_root():
    return subprocess.Popen(['git', 'rev-parse', '--show-toplevel'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].rstrip()#.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Dupe: this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28889252/7505395   or  this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42653179/7505395 or as a dirty hack - go upwards until you find a `.svn` directory - this may fail.

Comment: If those do not help edit your question and ping me to repopen.